# A Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7bd65fbf90 in tid 13277 (RenderThread), pid 13116

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When using Compose I encountered a crash. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

```
     A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7bd65fbf90 in tid 13277 (RenderThread), pid 13116 (my_package)
     A  Cmdline: my_package
     A  pid: 13116, tid: 13277, name: RenderThread  >>> my_package <<<
    ---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (13116) for package my_package ----------------------------
    E  win=Window{19d45ef u0 my_package/com.core.ActivityScreen EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true
win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 
caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5967 
com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:225 
com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6192 
com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onAnimationFinished:2 
com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:140 
com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.$r8$lambda$lRxTVOJy8fX752UbrFno9INW9hE:0 
com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run:8
```

Comment: I think you might have to share some code. 